# how to update values for only the most recent date in a pandas df of stock market technical indicators

Tags: python, pandas, google-play, ta-lib

I am using ta-lib library with python and pandas to first query SQL server for Ticker, Open, High, Low, Close and Volume, then ta-lib calculates the indicator values and created dataframe and then writes results to csv. The problem I am having is that it is recalculating all of the same values day every day and writing to the csv (including the most recent value of course), but I just want it to read from SQL (some of the indicators require reading back 50 days or so calculate the indicator value for each day), and just write one more row to the existing csv, rather that repopulating them over and over. (lots of unnecessary cpu). I have pandas set to 'w' for 'write' rather than append. Appending doesn't help at all. It just recalculates all technical indicator values and writes new duplicate rows after the preceding ones. Even when set to 'w', strangely it doesn't delete and recreate a new file, it just overwrites everything in the existing one which I guess is ok. But how can I tell pandas to just calculate the values for only that day, and write only that day's values to the last row in the file?
Here is what the results look like. I only want to populate the highlighted row on 1-25-2021, not redo all of the prior ones.
[image]

here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import talib
import os
from talib import (AD,ADOSC,WILLR)

exchanges = ["KO","SG"]

    for ex in exchanges:
        path = f'H:\\EOD_DATA_RECENT\\INDICATORS\\FROM-SQL-SOURCE\\{ex}\\'

        DB_READ = {'servername': 'XYZ\XYZ',
          'database': 'olaptraderv3'}

        conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + DB_READ['servername'] + ';DATABASE=' + 
        DB_READ['database'] + ';Trusted_Connection=yes')

        sql = f"""
        SELECT [Ticker], [Date], [Open], [High], [Low], [Close], [Volume] FROM olaptraderv3.dbo.{ex} 
        order by 
        Ticker
        """

    df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)

    for Ticker, df in df.groupby('Ticker'):
        df['AD'] = AD(df['High'], df['Low'], df['Close'], df['Volume']).round(5)
        df['ADOSC'] = ADOSC(df['High'], df['Low'], df['Close'], df['Volume'], fastperiod=3, 
        slowperiod=10)
        df['WILLR'] = WILLR(df['High'], df['Low'], df['Close'], timeperiod=14)
        df.to_csv(path+'{}.csv'.format(Ticker), mode='w', header=True, index=False,           
        index_label=False)

        print(df.tail(1))
```

#### Thanks, this suggestion worked.

Comment: `df.tail(1).to_csv(path+'{}.csv'.format(Ticker), mode='a', header=False)` This will append the last line to the existing CSV file without a header.

Comment: note that in your case 50-days history is a period that is a minimal for calculation. It doesn't mean that you can step 50 days back and calculate the same result as you would get if you step 100 days back for indicator calculation. If you need a precise results without recalculation of the whole data you better consider [TA-Lib RT](https://github.com/trufanov-nok/ta-lib-rt) - a fork of original TA-Lib which may save indicator calculation states and resume when new data arrives. It has experimental [wrapper](https://github.com/trufanov-nok/ta-lib-py-wrapper) for python.

Comment: some indicators require just 10 days, or just a few days, not 50. I dont know if I can prevent it from recalculating the indicators/days that it previously calculated, but I can tell it to not re-write those rows. This is why I will take the first guy's suggestion for df.tail(1). I can see that ta-lib requires all those back days to calculate most of the indicators but if I tell it not to re-write the rows, that's good enough for me, despite the unnecessary CPU